# String.Format is not working as expected C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to format content of my file like this:

```
0126252019-05-06 14:47:06 1098500020
```

But everytime I'm getting this results:

```
01262524. 5. 2019. 14:47:08 1098500020
```

Obliviously date and time are not formated as I wanted.

Here is my code:

```
StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\MyMainFolder\\MyFilesFolder\\" + 15050 + ".flr");
file.WriteLine(12625.ToString("D6") + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now + " " + 1098500020));
file.Close();
```

I've tried to format `DateTime.Now` as I wrote

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"
```

But looks like its not working

Thanks guys

Cheers!

Comment: You are passing `DateTime.Now + " " + 1098500020` to `string.Format` which isn't going to be parsed by that format string.

Comment: as david said: move `+ " " + 1098500020` before the `, DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `DateTime.Now + " " + 1098500020` to `string.Format` which isn't going to be parsed by that format string you have specified. To fix that you should move the `)`.

However, you should create the entire string, *including the prefix*, with `string.Format`, or for clearer code use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), for example:

```
var someInteger = 12625;
var line = $"{someInteger:D6}{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} 1098500020";
```

Comment: yeah I realized it after you left a comment, I will accept it as answer asap. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `+` is applied as string concatenation in the expression below:

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now + " " + 1098500020);
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                         C# makes this one string, and passes it for formatting.
```

Moving the concatenation that you plan to do inside the format string will fix the problem:

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} 1098500020", DateTime.Now);
```